# aws linux virtualenv install twisted

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, virtualenv, amazon-linux

I have a weird issue with twisted library on aws linux:

Using aws ec2 instance, aws linux. `python 3.6.5` (virtualenv)

For some reason `twisted` library is not getting properly installed.
`pip install twisted` showing success and no errors.
`pip install requirements.txt` where requirements contain `twisted` outputs that library was successfully installed among with other requirements.

however `pip list` after that doesn't show `twisted` and the code doesn't work either (twisted module missing).

```
Successfully installed Automat-0.7.0 Django-2.0.6 PyHamcrest-1.9.0 PyJWT-1.6.4 aioredis-1.1.0 altgraph-0.15 apscheduler-3.5.1 asgiref-2.3.2 async-timeout-3.0.0 attrs-18.1.0 autobahn-18.6.1 channels-2.1.1 channels-redis-2.2.1 configparser-3.5.0 constantly-15.1.0 daphne-2.2.1 django-cors-headers-2.3.0 django-extensions-2.0.7 djangorestframework-3.8.2 djangorestframework-jwt-1.11.0 future-0.16.0 gunicorn-19.7.1 hiredis-0.2.0 hyperlink-18.0.0 idna-2.7 incremental-17.5.0 jsonpickle-0.9.6 macholib-1.9 msgpack-0.5.6 pefile-2017.11.5 psycopg2-2.7.5 pyinstaller-3.3.1 pytz-2018.5 six-1.11.0 twisted-18.7.0 txaio-2.10.0 tzlocal-1.5.1 websocket-client-0.48.0 zope.interface-4.5.0
(environment) [ec2-user@ip********** ~]$ pip list
Package                 Version   
----------------------- ----------
aioredis                1.1.0     
altgraph                0.15      
asgiref                 2.3.2     
async-timeout           3.0.0     
attrs                   18.1.0    
autobahn                18.6.1    
Automat                 0.7.0     
channels                2.1.1     
channels-redis          2.2.1     
configparser            3.5.0     
constantly              15.1.0    
daphne                  2.2.1     
Django                  2.0.6     
django-cors-headers     2.3.0     
django-extensions       2.0.7     
djangorestframework     3.8.2     
djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0    
future                  0.16.0    
gunicorn                19.7.1    
hyperlink               18.0.0    
idna                    2.7       
incremental             17.5.0    
jsonpickle              0.9.6     
macholib                1.9       
meld3                   1.0.2     
pefile                  2017.11.5 
pip                     18.0      
PyHamcrest              1.9.0     
PyJWT                   1.6.4     
pytz                    2018.5    
setuptools              40.0.0    
six                     1.11.0    
supervisor              4.0.0.dev0
txaio                   2.10.0    
tzlocal                 1.5.1     
websocket-client        0.48.0    
wheel                   0.31.1
```

Please advise on how can i debug it or what might be a possible reason.

**UPDATE:**
i was able to make it work by installing twisted with `easy_install`. But it's still not the right solution as it must be done in addition to `requrements.txt` dependencies.

No luck making it work with `pip install`. there is only one python in virtualenv.

**update:** 
requirements.txt

```
Django==2.0.6
django-extensions==2.0.7
channels==2.1.1
channels-redis==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
django-cors-headers==2.3.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
jsonpickle==0.9.6
six==1.11.0
websocket-client==0.48.0
apscheduler==3.5.1
pyinstaller==3.3.1
configparser==3.5.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
msgpack==0.5.6
twisted==18.7.0
```

Comment: Should be `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: sry, you comment is irrelevant

Comment: Well, you said there was no errors, and `pip install requirements.txt` definitely throws and error. `pip freeze` is what is used to create the requirements file, not `pip list`

Comment: i guess there is some significant misunderstanding. there is *no* issues with installing requirements from the file or with `pip install twisted` itself. please read the post once again.

Comment: I understand fine. `Successfully installed  ... twisted`... but `pip list | grep twisted` would be empty, however, you have not shown `pip freeze` or shown your requirements file, so that is where I am confused as we need to be able to recreate your issues.

Comment: added full requirements list

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing this issue when I run `pip install setuptools` in MacOS.

Comment: that was a problem with amazon linux, but you could try checking if all packages are installed in the same `/lib` directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Amazon Linux as described here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4464

`pip` is installed some libraries in `/lib64` while most were in `/lib`.

Solutions:

- use `pip --target` to force install to `lib`
- run `unset PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT`
- use `Amazon Linux 2`